# How to change default/Active build configuration from 'Debug' on workspace launch?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, buildconfiguration, xilinx-edk

I have multiple custom Build Configurations in my project as shown below:
[Screenshot of build configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3Zmz.png)

On workspace setup by default it opens up in *'Debug'* configuration. I must have this changed to *'Rev8 Release'* (one of my custom configuration) instead.

One way I could achieve this by manually editing .cprojects file(the auto generated project settings file) and pasting the *'Rev8 Release'* configuration before the *'Debug'*. But I need a proper  method(by changing project settings) to do this without manually editing the **'.cprojects'**

Answer (score 0):

I propose checking out ManagedBuildManager. It can be used to retrieve / modify the Build Info of your project.

```
IManagedBuildInfo info = ManagedBuildManager.getBuildInfo(iproject); //iproject is the currently selected project in Project Explorer
IConfiguration [] buildConfigs = info.getManagedProject().getConfigurations(); //Get the available build configurations of the project
info.setDefaultConfiguration(buildConfigs[i] ); //Set default build configuration
try {
ManagedBuildManager.saveBuildInfo(iproject, true); //Apply changes
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: could you please detail about the solution. I was searching about ManagedBuildManager but couldn't help with my issue Iam using xilinx sdk.

Comment: info.setDefaultConfiguration does exactly what you are asking for: